# How to create a dataframe with rolling Linear Regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to perform a rolling linear regression on a dataframe, using a 3 window frame rolling, like shown below:

[image]

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm1 = LinearRegression()

x = np.asanyarray(df[['YEAR']])
y = np.asanyarray(df[['SALES']])

x_for_year6 = x[2:5] # data shown in red on the screenshot
y_for_year6  = y[2:5] # data shown in red on the screenshot

lm1.fit(x_for_year6 , y_for_year6 ) # Creates trend line

y_hat_year6= lm1.predict(x[5:6]) # Prediction for year 6
```

I got the prediction for the first year right (year 6), but after predicting year 6, I need to create a new regression line using the last 3 datapoints (including the one just predicted) and predict the next year. I think if I use rolling I could get it, but I am not having success.

EDIT: I tried using the following code, as sugested by jorijnsmit,

```
df['SALES'].rolling(3).apply(lm1.predict)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Is there a way of overcoming the error wihout converting to a numpy array? Because I would like to apply it on the dataframe

Comment: `df['SALES'].rolling(3).apply(lm1.predict)`

Comment: @jorijnsmit, thank you for your help.

I am getting the following error: "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1)"

Is there a way of overcoming the error wihout converting to a numpy array?

Comment: The last error probably asks you to reshape `lm1.predict`, not the dataframe. In any case, you should post the full error messages here, not truncate them.